Azure CI Pipeline Not Preparing Minified Files using BundlerMinifier into Artifact
Utilizing Azure CI Pipelines to help build and prepare my artifact for deployment, the minified files seem to be excluded from the prepared artifact.
Looking at the build logs I can see the files get minified successfully:
Bundler: Begin processing bundleconfig.json Minified wwwroot/.../script.min.js
The build successfully minifies the files but the artifact is missing them. The files aren't in the wrong directory or anything they are completely missing from the artifact.
Here is the CI Build Step:
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: Build Solution
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

NuGet used for bundling/minifying: https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier
Issue(not raised by me, I did try the "solution" there but it didn't work) on their GitHub here: https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier/issues/518

Hi, Josh, you can add a script task after the build task to print the current file list and confirm whether the file exists. For example, use dir $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) /s on a Windows agent or ls -R $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) on a Linux agent.   You can run the pipeline with verbose logs configured to check if there is more information in the logs.

Since the process works locally but not in CI, there might be differences in the environment or configurations. You can compare if there is any software versions or environment difference between your local and the pipeline agent.  You can also try to configure a self-hosted agent on your local agent where you successfully deployed these minified files. Then check if the file is there when you run the pipeline on the self-hosted agent.

dir $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) does indeed find the minified files in there.
I also confirmed something else recently. The process of publishing from Visual Studio doesnt actually properly create and publish these files either. The only reason I thought it was was because they were prebuilt in the environment from Visual Studio before the publish took place. So it will publish them, but it doesnt properly build them

Hi @Josh, thanks for your update, as you can indeed find the minified files in there, you can add a task to copy the files you need to the artifacts folder.

As you can find the at files get minified successfully form the log and dir $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) does indeed find the minified files in there, you can add a copy file task to copy the minified files to the artifact directory.
For example:
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: 'the path of the minified files'
    Contents: '**'
    TargetFolder: 'the path of your artifact directory'
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: 'the path of your artifact directory'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'

